# Conserved vector field with a potential function

Tags: potential-energy, conservative-field

I know that if a vector field is conservative then there exits a function such that the gradient of this function is equal to the vector field, but I am just curious to know the reason of it.

Comment: Since, conservative field has no curl, it can be expressed by the gradient of a scalar.

Comment: Oh I see! But why is the curl zero??

Comment: Curl is zero since there is no circulation in the field. Now, circulation means the dot product of the tangential component of the field with displacement around a closed curve- the _line integral_ of the field around the curve . Since, curl is zero, by Stokes theorem, the circulation is zero _everywhere_. This means the line integral from between any two points doesn't depend on the two paths. that's why, it is conservative meaning the line-integral just depends on the spatial coordinates which is just the scalar gradient.

Answer (score 1):

If a vector field is conservative, it means that the work done by is independent of the path taken,

The Work done is:

$$W=\int _a^b \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$

if the path is a closed curve $C$ then

$$W=\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$

According to the stokes theorem we know that 
$$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec A$$

where $S$ is the surface, and $dA$ is the differential area, 
For a conservative force the work done along a closed path is zero (since you return back to the same point), So

$$\int_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec A=0$$

$$\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$$

now we know that the curl of $F$ can be zero if $F$ is a gradient of a scalar or if $F$ is related to some $\vec{G}$ as $F=\nabla \cdot \vec{G}$, the latter is not particularly of interest

So, $F$ is a gradient of a scalar $V$

$$F=-\nabla V$$

Comment: Thank you!! But is it only the work done by a conservative force along a closed path is zero or its true for both conservative and non conservative forces?

Comment: @Za Kh No, its only true for conservative forces.

Comment: What do you mean by "if $F$ is related to some $\vec{G}$ as $F = \nabla \cdot \vec{G}$"?  The divergence of a vector field ($\nabla \cdot \vec{G}$) is a scalar, but $F$ is a vector.